# Check if class containing string exists in DOM (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, find

Is there a way to check the DOM for a class name containing the string "cookie"?, it can be .cookiesaved, .cookie-notice , .cookie-set , whatever as long as it contains the word "cookie" i need it to return `true`, and must be a class so i cannot use `indexOf` of the whole html document.

Also I can't use jQuery, so i'm trying to find a way via pure js.

What I'm trying to do is to check if the page has a cookie banner or not basically, and I couldn't come up with a better idea than checking for that class string so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for CSS attribute selectors: `[class*="cookie"]`, see MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors. E.g. `document.querySelector('[class*="cookie"]') !== null`